# Vanishing ideal is stable under Zariski closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.
For any set $S \subseteq k^n$, we define $I(S)$ to be the *vanishing ideal*, and we define $\overline{S}$ to be the closure of $S$ w.r.t. the Zariski topology, i.e. the smallest algebraic set containing $S$.

I want to show that $I(S) = I(\overline{S})$ for all $S \subseteq k^n$.
Preferably elementarily, *without* Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

One direction is rather obvious: Since $S \subseteq \overline{S}$, we have $I(\overline{S}) \subseteq I(S)$.

Comment: This feels too simple, but...suppose $f \in I(S)$. Then $f$ vanishes on some set $T$ which (1) contains $S$ and (2) is necessarily Zariski closed. By definition of the closure (intersection of all closed sets which contain $S$), $\overline S \subset T$ hence $f$ vanishes on $\overline S$, so $f \in I( \overline S)$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you very much, I don't know why I didn't came up with it. Strangely, I came up with a proof for $V(\mathfrak{a}) = V(\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}})$ easily.

Comment: @ronno Alright, I've typed it up as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f \in I(S)$. Then $f$ vanishes on some set $T$ which (1) contains $S$ and (2) is necessarily Zariski-closed. By the definition of closure (intersection of all closed sets which contain $S$), $\overline S \subset T$ hence $f$ vanishes on $\overline S$, so $f \in I(\overline S)$.